# opencv Perspective transformation then rotate 90 degree CW in one step

Tags: opencv, transformation

in opencv, i know i can use Perspective Transformation to do in this way:

```
pts1 = np.float32([[56,65],[368,52],[28,387],[389,390]])
pts2 = np.float32([[0,0],[300,0],[0,300],[300,300]])

M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)

dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img,M,(300,300))
```

https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html

then i can rotate the image by 90 degree by rotate function.

```
cv::rotate(image, image, ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE);
```

But i think i should be able to do the two steps in one step.

How should I create the matrix to multiple with PerspectiveTransform M,

i thought about this:

```
0 -1 0
1 0 0 
0 0 1
```

but this is wrong.

note: I will do it in Java.

Comment: you want to do this rotation in python? you can use rot90 from numpy for that it is only one instruction

Comment: i will do it in Java. and I think this can be done in 1 step for better efficiency.

Comment: once you defined your rotation matrix as a perspective teansformation matrix, you can just multiply both transformations in advance and then use the result for warping. Multiply in the right order. The first transformation to perform is on the right side in the multiplication.

Comment: i dont know what is the correct rotation matrix for this case, can you teach me? thanks.

Comment: google, wikipedia and SO can probably help. It will be a 3x3 matrix with some sin and cos entries, pre- and post- processed by some translations to rotate around a wanted center.

Comment: if you know the 3x3 matrix, please tell it. thanks.

Comment: if you dont know it, then giving the comment of why not google it, is not helpful at all..